# Vim - add one line above the fold to the folding

Tags: vim, fold, brackets

When I am coding in vim, I use `set foldmethod=syntax` which folds my code.
It looks something like this then:

[image]

How can I add the line above the `{` to the fold? So that it would look something like this:

[image]

So the idea is that it (always) takes the line above the fold into the fold.
How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a custom `fold expression` (`h fold-expr`) indenpendently from:

1. `foldtext` <-  you want to fold one more line
2. `foldignore` <- you still want to fold `{` and `}` whatever the indent

In your vimrc:

```
" Callback: Fold level <- next line indent
function! FoldMethod(lnum)
    let l:indent = max([indent(a:lnum+1), indent(a:lnum)])
    return l:indent / &shiftwidth
endfunction

set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=FoldMethod(v:lnum)
```